# How to set the caret position when there is an IMG element?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a content editable div like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">test1<img src="img.jpg"></img>test2</div>
```

Now, if I set the caret on position 5, I get this (the vertical line is the caret in the code below):

```
<div contenteditable="true">test1|<img src="img.jpg"></img>test2</div>
```

and if I set the caret on position 6, I get this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">test1<img src="img.jpg"></img>t|est2</div>
```

How can I set the caret right next to the IMG element? I want to get something like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">test1<img src="img.jpg"></img>|test2</div>
```

Comment: you should show the javascript code as well and the `img` tag is a self closing tag so it should only be `<img src="img.jpg" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the div has the content: "before `<img>` after", then basically there are 3 elements in it: 0.text:"before ", 1.img, 2.text: " after", and you want to be at the beginning of the #2:

```js
function setCaretPositionAfter1stImg(elemId) {
    var el = document.getElementById(elemId);
    if(el != null) {
      el.focus();
      var range = document.createRange();
      var sel = window.getSelection();
      range.setStart(el, 2);
      range.collapse(true);
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(range);
     }
}

setCaretPositionAfter1stImg("ed");
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="ed">test1<img src="img.jpg"/>test2</div>
```